# Limit of a series, at the boundary of convergence region

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $f(x)=\sum f_n (x)$ be a series, uniformly converging on some open set $D$.

For that matter I don't really care if $f_n$ are real or complex, so $D$ could be $(0,1)$ or $B_1(0)$ for example, depending on the type of series. I don't mind restricting to "simple" open sets (like intervals, balls, rings, half-planes), although I'm doubtful that the answer would depend on the type of open domain.

We may also assume that $f_n$ are nice functions, say analytic.

**Assume that $f(z)=\infty$ for $z\in\partial D$. Does it mean that $\lim_{x\to z} f(x)=\infty$?**

**By $f(z)=\infty$ I mean $\sum f_n(z)=\infty$.**

It sounds very logical to me, and the examples I have in mind for convering series do give a positive answer to my question. Yet, no proof comes to mind.

In the complex case, I can say that $f$ is analytic in $D$, and I would like to say that $z$ is some sort of pole - and we know that analytical functions aproach infinity near poles. Yet, this is problematic as $f$ is not defined in a a (punctured) neighborhood of $z$.

Comment: Do you mean that $D$ is an open set _in_ $\Bbb R^n$ (where we identify $\Bbb C$ with $\Bbb R^2$)?

Comment: Isn't it [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem#Remarks)?

Comment: If the series converges on $D$, what does "$f(z) = \infty$ for $z \in \partial D$" mean? We need some type of extension mechanism for that to be meaningful.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas yes

Comment: @ClementC. I wasn't aware of the extension given in the remarks (yet, it is without proof). But yes, it solves my question for the special case of real power series.

Comment: @DanielFischer What I meant is $\sum f_n (z)=\infty$ and $z\in\partial D$. This is more accurate, thanks.

Comment: @Thewayoflife I am 90% sure the proof is a minor adaptation of the proof of Abel's "regular" theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I guess the OP says the series converges for all $z\in D$ but diverges on the boundary of $D$ (since $D$ is open, it doesn't contain its boundary points $\partial D$).

Answer (score 1):

Following is a proposed solution.

Take $z_n \in D$ such that $\lim z_n = z$.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $g_n:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb R$ by $g_n(m)=f_m(z_n)$

Let us assume $g_n\geq0$. Then by Fatou's lemma (with respect to the counting measure on $\mathbb N$), 
$$\sum_m \liminf_{n}g_n(m)\leq\liminf_{n}\sum_m g_n(m)$$

If we assume $f_n$ is continuous, then $\liminf_{n}g_n(m)=f_m(z)$.
By our assumptions, $\sum_m f_m(z)=\infty$ and so we obtain 
$$\infty\leq\liminf_{n}\sum_m f_m(z_n)$$

which is what we wanted. Q.E.D